# How to not show the max and mini?

Tags: php, sql, max, min

I want to show all the price but not the max and mini.

I'm using NOT IN but it's not working.

```
<?php $cod_product = $_GET["cod_product"];

$sql = "SELECT `ppm`
                ,`price`
                ,`market`
                ,`product`
                ,`name_market`
                ,`cod_market`
    FROM ppm, markets
                WHERE product=$cod_product AND cod_market=market NOT IN (SELECT MAX(price), MIN(price) FROM ppm)
                ORDER BY price ASC";

        $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die("fail");

        if ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            do {

                $cod_market = $dados['market']; 
                $nome_mercado = $dados['name_market'];
                $price = $dados['price'];



             echo $price;
            echo $name_market;


            }
            while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($result));
            }else { }
            ?>
```

Comment: **Define exactly**, what do you mean by "_it's not working_". Is there an error? Does the result differ somehow from what you expect?

Comment: I'll assume there *is* an error, as there's no `mini` function in any DBMS I'm aware of.

Comment: @user1044413: "it's not working" and then "is dying".

Answer (score 2):

Change `mini()` to [`min()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) (assuming MySQL).

`mini()` isn't a function.

Also, some of your SQL doesn't make much sense.

```
  SELECT cod_ppm
         ,price
         ,market
         ,product
    FROM ppm
   WHERE price NOT IN (SELECT MAX(price), MIN(price) FROM ppm)
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Comment: ...and add a comma between the fields in the second query